# Why is my 'this' not changing context inside inner jQuery each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, each, method-chaining

The idea is that I want to loop through these objects and build an HTML structure which will be added to the page. I thought it would be cleaner to do it all in the chain, but apparently I'm not understanding something about the context of `this` as it evolves through inner loops. I've looked a bit at `jQuery.proxy()` a bit, but I'm not sure I understand how to apply it here. Maybe there is another way altogether of doing what I'm trying to do here...

```
var obj = [
    {"id":1213854620001,"name":"item 1","URL":"1213897576001.jpg"},
    {"id":1213854619001,"name":"item 2","URL":"1213890384001.jpg"},
    {"id":1213854618001,"name":"item 3","URL":"1213890378001.jpg"},
    {"id":1213854616001,"name":"item 4","URL":"1213897663001.jpg"},
    {"id":1213854615001,"name":"item 5","URL":"1213897554001.jpg"}
];
$(function() {
    if(obj.length) {
        $("<ul/>",{id:"myID"}).append(function(){
            var that = document.createDocumentFragment();
            $.each(obj,function(index,dataObj){
                $("<li/>",{data:{dataID:dataObj.id},text:dataObj.name}) // this === obj[index] === dataObj, shouldn't it be the [object HTMLLIElement]
                    .live("click",function(event) {
                        openVideo($(event.target).data(dataID));
                    })
                    .append(function() {
                        return $("<img/>",{src:dataObj.thumbnailURL})[0];
                    })
                    .appendTo(that);
            });
            return that;
        }).appendTo("body");
    }
});

function openVideo(str) {
    //console.log(str);
}
```

The implicit question becomes, why is `that` empty after my loop? and how can I build this HTML structure with nested loops?

Using the suggestions from the comments, and answers, I built this, which seems to work exactly as it should, reads a little cleaner, and lets jQuery do all the javascript (e.g. `documentFragment` creation, and manipulation, etc):

```
$(function() {
    if(obj.length) {
        $("<ul/>",{id:"myID"})
        .delegate("li","click",function(){openVideo($(this).data("dataID"));})
        .append(function() {
            var that = $(this);
            $.each(obj,function(index,dataObj) {
                $("<li/>",{data:{dataID:dataObj.id},text:dataObj.name}).each(function() {                   
                    $("<img/>",{src:dataObj.URL}).appendTo(this);
                    that.append(this);
                })
            });
        }).appendTo("body");
    }
});
```

Comment: Your use of `.live()` is incorrect. You really shouldn't be using `.live()` in the first place.

Comment: why is `.live()` incorrect here, the structure isn't in the `DOM` yet, I'm binding for the future?

Comment: `that` is referencing a `documentFragment`. jQuery doesn't like those so much.

Comment: `.live()` uses event delegation. You need to provide it a selector and bind to an ancestor, and you only do it once instead of in a loop. It doesn't bind in the future.

Comment: What do mean jQuery doesn't like those, it uses them all over the place see John Resig's [post](http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#6)

Comment: It uses them internally. You're trying to use it to add your newly created jQuery objects.

Comment: @RightSaidFred so, are you suggesting I move the `.live()` binding outside to the `UL` instead and parse the `event` from there?

Comment: The way live works is that it binds a handler to the `document`, and tests all clicks (or whatever event) on the page to see if it matches the selector you gave it. So before you create any elements, you'd do `$('li').bind('click',function() {...})`. But a better solution would be to use `.delegate()`, and either put the delegate handler on the new `ul`, or on an ancestor that encompasses all the `ul` elements you're creating if there are more than one.

Comment: ...generally speaking, document wide event delegation isn't the best solution. That's what `.live()` is.

Comment: OOPS: In the comment two above I wrote `bind` instead of `live`. My comment should show `$('li').live('click',function() {...})` instead of `$('li').bind('click',function() {...})`

Comment: Thank you for clearing `.live()` up for me @RightSaidFred that will help

Comment: You're welcome. FYI, if you do want to work with fragments, you just need to use native methods and elements. So when you create a new `<li>` with jQuery, you'd extract the DOM element, and use the native `.appendChild()` to add to the fragment. Then to append the fragment to the UL, instead of passing it to jQuery's `.append()`, you could pass its `.childNodes`. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/22tS3/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` changes meaning as you step into new nested functions.  It does **not** change meaning when you call `$()` to create a new element.

So immediately inside of

```
$.each(obj, function(index, dataObj) {
```

`this` is the current object over which your looping.  Once you get here:

```
.live("click",function(event) {  // <------  inside of nested function 
    openVideo($(event.target).data(dataID));
})
```

`this` is the element on which you clicked.

But calling

```
    $("<li/>",{data:{dataID:dataObj.id},text:dataObj.name})
```

to create a new `li` element does **not** set `this` to the newly created element.

---

Also, if you want to save the meaning of `this` even inside of nested functions, the standard way is to save it to a new variable.

```
$.each(obj, function() {
    var self = this;
```

Now `self` can be used instead of `this` as the item you're currently "on" anywhere in your loop, even in nested function handlers.  Or you can pass index and dataObjects to the each function - same effect.

**EDIT**

As a comment pointed out, you're using live incorrectly.  If you're using jQuery 1.7, you'll want:

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function(event) {
      openVideo($(this).data(dataID));
});
```

in your `document.ready` handler.  If all li's that will be clicked will be in a certain div, than select on that div instead of `document`.  If you don't want this click handler to apply to all li's, but only some, then decorate all the li's you want this click handler to apply to with a css class, then instead of passing the filter "li" to `on`, you'd pass `li.yourClass`

Comment: problem is it isn't changing to the freshly created LI element, which I'm chaining the subsequent methods to...

Comment: So, I'm still unclear as to why my chained methods are using `dataObj` instead of the jQuery object created (and returned by) `$("<li/>",{data:{dataID:dataObj.id},text:dataObj.name})`. Inside a jQuery method chain isn't `this` supposed to be the selector object at the beginning of the chain?

Comment: @bodine - `$("<li/>",{data:{dataID:dataObj.id},text:dataObj.name})` does not set this to the dom element you just created.  It's not supposed to.  I think you might be mixing up some things.

Comment: @AdamRackis thank you for steering me in the right direction here. I'm still not quite sure I understand why my `UL` wasn't getting built with the old method chain approach. Maybe it was related to the funky `.live()` attachment... Either way thanks for straightening me out on the misuse of `.live()`!

Answer (score 1):

`$.each` sets `this` for the inner function to be the element iterated (and yes, `this` is one of the complicated things in Javascript, but your comment can be explained by just referencing `each` behaviour).

Comment: `$("<li/>",{data:{dataID:dataObj.id},text:dataObj.name})` should reset `this` for the method chain that follows, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Could you please clarify your answer a bit?

Comment: Well, it depends at which _exact_ point you are dealing with `this`. The line where your comment is, is in the scope of `function(index,dataObj){...}`, and there `this` is set to `dataObj`, which is exactly how `$.each` behaves. Or do you have problem with `this` in different point of your code? Which one? `this` has strong function scope. It is potentially different for every (inner or not) function, and _is not inherited_ from outer scope, ever.

Comment: I guess my confusion is with the fact that even though there is a comment here (which is effectively a breakpoint in my debugger), I'm still in the method chain, right? So inside **those** chained methods `this` should not be `dataObj`, right?

Comment: Inside those chained methods it is your jquery set containing the `<li>` element, but is complicated even more, because `function(event) { openVideo($(event.target).data(dataID)); }` and `function() { return $("<img/>", {src:dataObj.thumbnailURL})[0]; }` are not chained, they are just some callbacks created on the spot and when they are called (later, maybe never), whoever calls them rules about what will `this` be (same as `$.each` ruled about `this` for `function(index,dataObj){ ... }`). So read the API documentation to see what `this` will be for those inner functions, when they are called.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, in prototype based languages, which javascript is one, functions are objects, and objects have properties. So when you use the 'this' keyword, it reverts to the scope of the current prototype. Inside of an 'inline function' (which is actually not a concept in javascript since functions are just objects), this refers to the function.